# ElasticSearch: is there any option to search in all fileds in document by simply giving the query in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am new to Elasticserach and am looking for a solution to our existing scenario. Suppose I have created a document:

```
{     
    "employee": {
        "properties": {
        "id"  : {"type": "string"},
        "value": {"type": "string"},
        "role": {"type": "string"},
        "desc": {"type": "string"}
     }
   }
}
```

And i would like to search on fields without specifying field name explicitly.

For example, if my search query string is "Bin", i would like to search in all fields id, value, role and desc. Is there any way to do in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the [_all](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html#mapping-all-field) field. It allows you to search a document without specifying field names.

Do read the documentation carefully, though, as:

> This comes at the expense of CPU cycles and index size.

Comment: Thank you it solved my issue, i missed to read this part and as you mentioned the performance it may be a concern in my case as we have big data but we can specific in terms of permance where do need to search.